# Intent do Instagram da erro no webview?

Tags: android, webview

Quando clico em abrir no aplicativo do instagram no meu aplicativo. Meu webview da o seguinte erro:

> Pagina da Web nao disponivel
>
> Nao foi possivel carregar a pagina da web no endereço
>   intent://instagram.com/_u/hotelcolonialdosnobres/#Intent;package=com.instagram.androi;scheme=https;end
>
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

No meu webview tenho essa função responsavel

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //  try{ url != null &&
        if (url.startsWith("http://www.hotelcolonialdosnobres.com/")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        if (url.startsWith("mailto:") ||url.startsWith("intent://") || url.startsWith("market://")  ){
            try {
                final   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
           final  Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
            host.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link  uri.getQuery())
               // Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

Como solucionar esso erro para que ele possa abrir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver o problema usando o seguinte código, funciona corretamente para abrir links no Instagram direto da sua aplicação.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/hotelcolonialdosnobres/");
Intent likeIng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

likeIng.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

try {
    startActivity(likeIng);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/hotelcolonialdosnobres/")));
}
```

Comment: Mais esse codigo nao vai funcionar se eu aperta para abrir o facebook